# Get Discord user current game AND custom status?

Tags: discord.js

Currently, using **Discord.js**, `member.user.presence.game.name` will return the game name IF said user doesn't have a custom status set, but if they do, this returns "Custom Status". Not their actual status, or their game name, just... "Custom status". I'd like to be able to return the game name and custom status both independently if they are set. Currently my code looks like:

```
    const embed = new RichEmbed()
    let statusField

    if (member.user.presence.status)
      statusField = statusField + `\n**► Status:** ${member.user.presence.status}`

    if (member.user.presence.game.name)
      statusField = statusField + `\n**► ${gameTypeToString(member.user.presence.game.type)}:** ${member.user.presence.game.name}`

    embed.addField("User Status", statusField)
    message.channel.send(embed);
```

Notes:

- As a side note for context, my embed is bigger and has more
  information in it, I'm just only showing the relevant pieces.
- I'm aware that `member.user.presence.status` is the online/idle/dnd/offline status, I am also displaying that in the embed, but along with the custom status and/or current game.
- `gameTypeToString` is a simple function that looks like this:

```
gameTypeToString: function(gameType) {
    switch (gameType) {
      case 0:
        return "Playing"
      case 1:
        return "Streaming"
      case 2:
        return "Listening to"
      case 3:
        return "Watching"
      default:
        return "Doing"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Looks like they currently might be working on this: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3552

Comment: This pull request was merged some days ago. Actually, on the master branch, we only can access to custom status **or** game....